# extracting strings/numbers in a list thats in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
x= [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,3,89,4],[1,1],[1,89],[1,7]]
print(x[1:2])
```

I intend on it printing 89 from the second list in the 3rd space but it just prints the whole list and not the number.

Comment: Are you aware that `x` is a tuple with 1 element, and not a tuple of several lists? All of the lines between the assignment to `x` and the `print` call have no effect.

Comment: You need another set of `[]` around the whole value of `x` to make it a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing slice syntax with array indexing.

What you *want* is `x[1][3]`. Since x is a list of lists, then `x[1]` is a list, and `x[1][3]` is an element from that list.

What you're *doing* is creating a slice of `x` from index `1` to index `3`, stepping forward `3` elements each time. The syntax for a slice is `list[start:end:step]`.

---

Also, python will interpret `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],` as a 1-tuple, on its own. You need to either encase all of those lists in a single set of square-brackets, or put them all on a single line.